# youtube api v3 search by developer tag

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-api-client

my app upload video to youtube, i need  user see what other user upload (or in another word search by developer tag).

i'm use this way https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert to upload videos.

i saw this link to show how to do this but in version 2.0, i'm use v3

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Assigning_Developer_Tags

i need simple explanation how to attach developer tag in v3

thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

You can set [categoryId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.categoryId) while inserting the video.

That id will represent a [videoCategory](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list).

Comment: when i add snippet.setCategoryId("test"); the video dont upload, and there is no error on logcat, are you know why?

Comment: Category id is a videoCategory id. You should set a valid one as described above.

Comment: Is there any plan to add custom developer categories like in V2?

This is so that we can know what to expect and rely on going forward.