# Find and manage all YouTube uploads by app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels, android-youtube-api

My app upload videos to YouTube using "direct upload".
[I use version 3.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

i need that after the user uploaded his video I (app owner) and the user will be able to manage the videos (delete or edit the video), all this through the website of YOUTUBE(At the entrance to the URL,video list appear ). Currently only the user can edit or delete his videos.

In addition user will  find the videos (all videos uploaded by the app) by a URL (like a playlist) this list will Sort by views  or by rating.

Maybe the answer is a playlist, or channel???, whether i will use channel or playlist the users  Be allowed to add their videos to my playlist or to my channel? the users Be allowed to delete their video?

[I received An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518932/youtube-api-v3-search-by-developer-tag), to my earlier questionbut, but I do not understand how categoryID is unique  to my application?

Answer (score 0):

According to [YouTube v2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_updating_and_deleting_videos) You can delete it if you have access token and developer key.
Like this:

```
DELETE /feeds/api/users/default/uploads/VIDEO_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
```

So deleting by user request is not a problem. Deleting by your own need to be tested, it depends if you can obtain application access token using some kind of app secret.
Parhaps [YouTube API v2.0 - OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Authentication) will give you the answer.