# Does YouTube Data API V3 support custom developer categories/tags (like in V2)?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-client, youtube-data-api

Follow up to: [youtube api v3 search by developer tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518932/youtube-api-v3-search-by-developer-tag/) which indicates that you can a use *valid* pre-existing categoryIds but it does not answer anything about how to use *custom* Developer Categories/Tags.

In YouTube API V2, *custom* Developer Categories/Tags are described here: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Assigning_Developer_Tags

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request. Please see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5012

Comment: Ok, that answers my question, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube's migration document lists the following alternative:

*Set or retrieve developer tags – The v2 API supported the ability to associate keywords, or developer tags, with a video at the time that the video was uploaded. Developer tags would not be displayed to YouTube users, but video owners could retrieve videos that matched a specific developer tag.
The v3 API's search.list method supports a similar, but not identical, feature with its forDeveloper filter parameter, which restricts a search to only retrieve videos uploaded via the developer's application or website. The forDeveloper parameter can be used in conjunction with optional search parameters like the q parameter.
For this feature, each uploaded video is automatically tagged with the project number that is associated with the developer's application in the Google Developers Console.
When a search request subsequently sets the forDeveloper parameter to true, the API server uses the request's authorization credentials to identify the developer. Therefore, a developer can restrict results to videos uploaded through the developer's own app or website but not to videos uploaded through other apps or sites.*

ref: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Developer tags in V3 are currently not supported (c.f. question comments). If enough people vote on this feature request, they might be in the future: 
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5012