# YouTube API v3 - How to Identify Client Specific Video Uploads

Tags: youtube-data-api

Is there any property associated with the Video or PlaylistItem YouTube entities to identify videos that were uploaded via my application (for example, are they associated to my application's Name, ClientID, APIKey, etc.)?

If not, what are some suggestions to track/tag which videos where actually uploaded via my application using YouTube API v3? **Not all content in my user's channels are to be managed through my application.**

Background info: I've used video categories in previous versions of the API for identifying managed videos, but in v3 a video is limited to one category. I didn't find anything to address this in the v3 migration document, but admittedly using the categories could have been a hack learned back v1 that also happened to work in v2. 
I am using the Google APIs Client Library for .NET in my application.

Comment: Your question is too broad - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I wouldnt say the question is too broad, but OP have you read this? https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters Specifically the `author` param...

Comment: If the author is the logged in user, I still have a problem because my user's may be using the same credentials in my application as they do outside of it, leaving me unable to identify what actually should be managed by my app. Otherwise this could work if there is a way to set the author in API v3.

Answer (score 0):

The "forDeveloper"(bool) property on the Search:list request looks to be the solution in YouTube API v3 going forward.

See this related question for more detail:
[Does YouTube Data API V3 support custom developer categories/tags (like in V2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736803/does-youtube-data-api-v3-support-custom-developer-categories-tags-like-in-v2)

If someone has a suggestion for identifying content uploaded before API v3 I'm all ears. My application's uploaded 8M+ videos using the v2 category tags for identification before this migration to API v3...